# Is there a way to set the amount of columns per page shown in a bootstrap studio site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-studio

Okay, so I am using Bootstrap studio to create a site with multiple cards on each page, and initially used cards from the sb-admin-2 template. All was going great- in my bootstrap studio view, my three-column card widths are the same and are next to each other in the right way. However, when I test the code in the browser, it only shows a two-column layout. I'm guessing this is a CSS related issue related to the col constraints set by the sb-admin-template (included in the code section below), but I'm confused how to override them to rectify the column layout. I just need this specific layout for this specific page, so I'm not sure what to do.

I've tried overwriting this by duplicating/editing the code in my style sheet and shutting off the constraints below. but for some reason, it isn't working.

[Bootstrap Studio View of Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLcPd.png)

[Browser view of columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi3Lu.png)

```
.col, .col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-auto, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-auto, .col-md, .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-auto, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-auto, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-auto {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: .75rem;
  padding-left: .75rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS priorities from lowest to highest:

• Tag selectors (lowest priority), `div {...} span {...}` etc.

• class selectors `.class {...}`

• `#id {...}`

• inline styles `style="..."`

• `anything { property: value !important; }`

Using important is bad practice, because in future you may want to overwrite the important style, and sometimes there is no way. + It can cause problems in JavaScript.

So, firstly you can try to add an id to body tag. And give that styles to selector

`#body-id .col, #body-id .col-1 ....` or maybe `#body-id [class^="col"] {...}`

If that will not help...

```
width: 100% !important;
padding-right: .75rem !important;
padding-left: .75rem !important;
```

Comment: thank you for responding. So far, I have tried both, and my browser preview looks the same. I am confused- I gave an id to the container with the columns, and have even tried taking out some of the column options to see if that would change things, but so far it hasn't. I am rusty with html/css so I might just be misunderstanding what you are trying to say though?  this is what I have tried most recently:  #container.user .col-md-3, {
  width: 100% !important;
  padding-right: 75rem !important;
  padding-left: 75rem !important;
}

Comment: @EmmaChisholm Yes, but without comma... `#container.user .col-md-3 { ...`

Comment: Hi again, so sorry to bother you! So I have tried that, and nothing happened? and I have also tried changing the padding to see if its that as well, and I still don't know where I'm going wrong. Do you think this could be an html related problem? or css?